# R: Question about Optimizing - Invalid Function Value in Optimize

Tags: r, optimization

We have not been able to pinpoint what is causing the error of `Invalid Function Value in Optimize` in our Optimizing code. If you could offer any insight, it would be appreciated.

```
H_fun <- function(c) 
{ 
val = -current_c_weight*c - X_counts%*%log( 
exp(rep(c,length(current_Theta))*current_Theta) - 
current_elongation_rates ) 
print('#########iteration display#############') 
print('c') 
print(c) 
print('val') 
print(val) 
print('current_c_weight') 
print(current_c_weight) 
print('current_Theta') 
print(current_Theta) 
print('current_elongation_rates') 
print(current_elongation_rates) 
} 

#...snip...

# minimize -H(c) without the non-negativity constraint 
#tmp = optim(c(0,1),H_fun,NULL, method = "BFGS", hessian = TRUE); 
tmp = optimize(H_fun,interval = c(0,1));
```

Here is a link to the code:

http://www.text-upload.com/read.php?id=102950&c=8605046

Comment: Unfortunately your example is not reproducible.  Please post the values of `current_c_weight`, `X_counts`, `current_Theta` and `current_elongation_rates`.

Comment: @Andrie, the full source code is at the text-upload.com link.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you sure `H_fun` is returning a one-dimensional value?

Look at `fcn1()` in the [R `optimize()` source code](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/d541113a8f7b9a139292104400249cf9fb2a3651/src/library/stats/src/optimize.c#L209):

```
static double fcn1(double x, struct callinfo *info)
{
    SEXP s;
    REAL(CADR(info->R_fcall))[0] = x;
    s = eval(info->R_fcall, info->R_env);
    switch(TYPEOF(s)) {
    case INTSXP:
        if (length(s) != 1) goto badvalue;
        if (INTEGER(s)[0] == NA_INTEGER) {
            warning(_("NA replaced by maximum positive value"));
        return DBL_MAX;
        }
        else return INTEGER(s)[0];
        break;
    case REALSXP:
        if (length(s) != 1) goto badvalue;
        if (!R_FINITE(REAL(s)[0])) {
            warning(_("NA/Inf replaced by maximum positive value"));
            return DBL_MAX;
        }
        else return REAL(s)[0];
        break;
    default:
        goto badvalue;
    }
 badvalue:
    error(_("invalid function value in 'optimize'"));
    return 0;/* for -Wall */
}
```

`goto badvalue` occurs if length is not 1. Also, the [package summary](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Optimization.html) states that optimize() works on a one-dimensional unconstrained function.