# Why does repeating a loop change the results of looped optimization?

Tags: r, loops, optimization

My original function embodies several optimize() functions, for which I get different results when I apply the function the first time vs. second time.

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6658941/r-question-about-optimizing-invalid-function-value-in-optimize) but I made sure that the returned value is one-dimensional.

```
fn = function(A,P){
  l_fn = function(x) {
    L <- x[1]
    -((A*L*P)-(P*L^2)) # -1 because optimize-function finds minimum
  }
  l_opt <- as.numeric(optimize(l_fn,c(0,1000))[2]) # get objective output
  return(l_opt)
}

f <- data.frame(x=c(10:20))

for (i in 1:length(f)) { # run this part 2 times!
  f$test <- sin(f$x) # this is how I expect a function to behave
  f$out[i] <- fn(f$x[i],100) 
}
```

running the code the first time produces f$out that are all equal (weird). running the for loop again changes f$out, eventhough the input parameters remain the same! How is that possible?

Comment: Did you try to create the `out` column before you run the loop the first time? I.e. create an empty column for the output like this: `f <- data.frame(x=c(10:20), out=rep(NA, length(c(10:20)))`? Setting a not yet existent column of a data.frame to a certain value assigns this value to each row of the column.

Comment: At the start of the loop, `length(f)` is 1.  It only runs through the loop once.  You should use `nrow(f)` instead.  It's also better form in R to use `seq_len(nrow(f))` instead of `1:nrow(f)`.